# CSS not Loading when accessing page from another page

Tags: html, css

When I click a link in my nav bar of my "ABOUT" page, it takes me to the barebones HTML of the "HOME" page and doesn't display any of the styling. I have linked the CSS to both the "HOME" page and the "ABOUT" page.

```
<head>
    <title>About Me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
  <script src="photosite.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Sorry if this has been asked, first post here and very new to Web Dev.

Comment: Are your `Home` and `About` pages located in the same directory?

Comment: It gets asked over and over and over again on SO even when there are countless same questions answered all over the internet. Did [none of these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+not+loading) help you?

Comment: @BryanElliott Yes, they're in the same directory. They're in the same Finder Folder, just to be extra clear.

Comment: can you share your  nav bar code

Comment: @ABCD 
`<div>
    <nav style="text-align: center; margin: auto; letter-spacing: 2px">
     <a href="TS_Photo.html" style="color:black;">HOME</a>
     <a href="" style="color:black;">ABOUT</a>
     <a href="" style="color:black;">WORK</a>
     <a href="" style="color:black;">CONTACT</a>
    </nav>
   </div>`

Comment: for about ,contact,work href="" empty right??

Comment: give path like href="TS_Photo.html" ,then try again